# Where are PHP extensions when installing from source?

Tags: php, linux

When I try to run a PHP scripts I get the following errors:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/user/php-5.4.28/installdir/include/php/ext/php_bz2.so' - /home/user/php-5.4.28/installdir/include/php/ext/php_bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "/home/user/php-5.4.28/installdir/include/php/ext"
```

Content at extension_dir path:

```
~/php-5.4.28/installdir/include/php/ext$ ls
date  ereg    gd    iconv  libxml    mysqli   pcre  session  sqlite3   xml
dom   filter  hash  json   mbstring  mysqlnd  pdo   spl      standard
```

Where do I locate the extension?
I have installed PHP from source.
All the errors and phpinfo() can be seen [here on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/liqecixu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to locate the extension. You have to recompile PHP passing the option `--with-bz2` to the `./configure` script. Bzip2 support is not enabled by default as [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/bzip2.installation.php) says.

```
./configure --with-bz2
```

Keep in mind that in order to compile PHP with this extension you need development headers and/or libraries. If they are missing `./configure` will fail saying what's missing. If this will happen simply use your package manager (apt, yum or zypper - distro dependent) to install required packages and retry.

It's also likely that your PHP apps are using other extensions. The procedure is exactly the same. You just add more options. Let's say that curl is also needed, then:

```
./configure --with-bz2 --with-curl
```

will work - again more headers and packages needed.

Remember to always use all the options you need as the results of former compilations are overwritten.

Comment: I'm aware of that and therefor my config code includes the extensions I need. But I still get the errors mentioned in the question. I had: ./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql --with-zlib --enable-calendar --with-curl --enable-ftp --with-gd --enable-exif --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql

Comment: But you don't have `--with-bz2` as I said.